# Подключение к БД средствами Spring с указанием кодировки сессии

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Дело в том, что развернув приложение на хостинге столкнулся с проблемой кодировки, везде использую UTF-8, отследил весь путь и выявил, что с контролёра в базу(mySQL) попадают `?????`. Весь проект на аннотациях(Spring), в `@Configuration` классе подключаюсь к базе:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*******");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("*******");
        return ds;
    }
```

Как указать кодировку при подключении jdbc:mysql://…/…?characterEncoding=UTF-8, только не в xml, а в бине?

Comment: указать в jdbc url

Comment: ....Не знаю как

Comment: вы же написали сами, ?characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name_db?characterEncoding=UTF-8):

Comment: так же у вас можеть создана база даных с другой кодировкой и проблема совсем не в настройке...

Comment: Да, но не в xml файле, у меня его нет вовсе, мне нужно указать это в @Bean

Comment: Связался с суппортом и в php админе смотрел - utf-8. Если не сохранять данные в базу, а отправлять в браузер, то всё корректно, так что остаётся только база

Comment: Работает, я тупил и не туда пытался прилепить этот ?characterEnco‌​ding=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в datasource
`ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name_db?characterEnco‌​ding=UTF-8)`